# pandas set column values for rows based on the number of rows with the same value on another column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following `dataframe` with 4 columns,

```
cluster_a  cluster_b  cluster_c  cluster_d
-1         1           10        -1
-1         3           9         -1
 1         1           3          4
 1         1           3          4
 2         2           9          9
 2         2           9          9
```

for rows with values > `-1` for `cluster_a`, I want to set their column values to `-1` for `cluster_b` or `cluster_c` or `cluster_d`, if these rows do not have the same values for any of these columns from row(s) whose `cluster_a` == `-1`. But leave the column values intact if these rows can find corresponding values in row(s) whose `cluster_a` == `-1`.

rows with the same `cluster_a` value, also having the same values for the rest of the columns.

so the result `df` looks like,

```
cluster_a  cluster_b  cluster_c  cluster_d
-1         1           10        -1
-1         3           9         -1
 1         1          -1         -1
 1         1          -1         -1
 2        -1           9         -1
 2        -1           9         -1
```

here rows

```
 1         1           3          4
 1         1           3          4
```

have the same cluster_a value and this value is > -1, we consider them as in the same group (`id_rows` in the code), since their `cluster_b` value is the same as the 1st row in `df`,

```
 -1         1           10        -1
```

their `cluster_b` will not be set to `-1`.

However, not so for their `cluster_c` and `cluster_d`, since their `cluster_c` and `cluster_d` could not find the same values in rows whose `cluster_a` == `-1`, which are

```
 -1         1           10        -1
 -1         3           9         -1
```

the result of the above two rows whose `cluster_a` == `1` is hence

```
  1         1          -1         -1
  1         1          -1         -1
```

this is my code,

```
# get unique cluster_a values which are > -1
cluster_a_ids = df[df['cluster_a'] > -1]['cluster_a'].unique() 
other_clusters = ['cluster_b', 'cluster_c', 'cluster_d']
# iterate through unique cluster_a values
for id in cluster_a_ids:
    # get the rows whose cluster_a == id
    id_rows = df[df['cluster_a'] == id]
    # iterate through the other columns
    for cluster in other_clusters:
        # find rows from df where e.g. cluster_b == value in cluster_b column of id_rows
        match_rows = df[df[cluster] == id_rows[cluster].values[0]]
        if match_rows.shape[0] == id_rows.shape[0]:
            df.loc[match_rows.index, cluster] = -1
```

I am wondering if there is a more concise/efficient way to do it.

Comment: How many rows with cluster_a `-1` are present ?

Comment: @Bharath that could be many rows with `cluster_a` == `-1`, I just created a minimal example here

Comment: If possible can you add an explanation of how your approach works with comments or add another set of rows with -1 in `cluster_a` to get more insights

Comment: `same values for these columns on row(s) whose cluster_a == -1` this part is bit confusing.You are not checking for this condition in your loop. So its better to explain a bit about your approach.

Comment: @Bharath sry for the ambiguation, have modified my op, should be much clear now